# How to generate a date array and forward fill missing data using BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with weeks of missing data (shown below):

```
        week    | customer_id  |  score
     -----------|--------------|---------
     2019-10-27 |     1        |    3
     2019-11-10 |     1        |    4
     2019-10-20 |     2        |    5
     2019-10-27 |     2        |    8
```

Therefore I've used BigQuery's GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY function to fill in the missing weeks for each customer (in the range 2019-10-20 to 2019-11-10), which results in a NULL customer_id and score value for those weeks that were missing (shown below).

```
    week    | customer_id  |  score
 -----------|--------------|---------
 2019-10-20 |    NULL      |   NULL
 2019-10-27 |     1        |    3
 2019-11-03 |    NULL      |   NULL
 2019-11-10 |     1        |    4
 2019-10-20 |     2        |    5
 2019-10-27 |     2        |    8
 2019-11-03 |    NULL      |   NULL
 2019-11-10 |    NULL      |   NULL
```

I want to forward fill the customer_id and score for each customer using the last non-null value so that the table looks like this:

```
    week    | customer_id  |  score
 -----------|--------------|---------
 2019-10-20 |    NULL      |   NULL
 2019-10-27 |     1        |    3
 2019-11-03 |     1        |    3
 2019-11-10 |     1        |    4
 2019-10-20 |     2        |    5
 2019-10-27 |     2        |    8
 2019-11-03 |     2        |    8
 2019-11-10 |     2        |    8
```

I wrote this query, however, since the customer_id value is NULL in some rows, I am unable to partition by this field and it is instead returning NULL values. If I filter for WHERE customer_id = 1 and remove the PARTITION BY clause, I get the desired result, but I cannot get it to work for multiple customers.

```
 WITH weeks AS 
    (SELECT created_week
    FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2019-10-20', '2019-11-10', INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) week 
    ),
    table AS 
    (SELECT *, DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE FROM created_at), WEEK) AS week, 
    FROM score
    )
    
    SELECT weeks.week,
    COALESCE(table.customer_id, LAST_VALUE(table.customer_id IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY table.customer_id ORDER BY weeks.week)) AS customer_id,
    COALESCE(table.score, LAST_VALUE(table.score IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY table.customer_id ORDER BY weeks.week)) AS score,
    FROM weeks
    LEFT JOIN table
        ON weeks.week = table.week
```

I am wondering how I can generate this date array for each customer and then somehow forward fill any missing data using the last customer_id and score value for that customer. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Edit your question and show what your sample data looks like.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks just made the edit

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is just to generate the data as you need it:

```
select the_week, t.customerid, t.score
from (select DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE FROM created_at), WEEK) AS week, 
             customerid, score,
             lead(DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE FROM created_at), WEEK)) over (partition by customerid order by created_at) as next_week
      from t
     ) t cross join
     unnest(generate_date_array(t.week,
                                date_add(t.next_week, interval -1 week),
                                interval 1 week
                               )) the_week;
```

By generating only the dates you need for each week, you don't need to "fill" anything in.  The only downside is that you don't get data before the first week.  You can fill that in if you really want, but it doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: I am getting an error saying "expected interval expression" for the DATE_ADD function.

Comment: @Sara . . . Ooops, I used the SQL Server syntax for that.

Comment: thank you, I appreciate it! Sorry I am fairly new to big query, so how would I change it to create a new week of data from each customers first week of data up until the current date? @GordonLinoff