# How to generate a date array up until the current week using BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I asked this question yesterday [How to generate a date array and forward fill missing data using BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67730146/how-to-generate-a-date-array-and-forward-fill-missing-data-using-bigquery/67730192?noredirect=1#comment119718931_67730192) to which @GordonLinoff kindly answered with this query:

```
select the_week, t.customerid, t.score
from (select DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE FROM created_at), WEEK) AS week, 
             customerid, score,
             lead(DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE FROM created_at), WEEK)) over (partition by customerid order by created_at) as next_week
      from t
     ) t cross join
     unnest(generate_date_array(t.week,
                                date_add(t.next_week, interval -1 week),
                                interval 1 week
                               )) the_week;
```

The above query works and answers the question I had originally asked, but I realized that I actually need to forward fill missing data at weekly intervals up until the current date. I tried replacing the `date_add` function with `DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE FROM current_datetime(), WEEK)` but it didn't work unfortunately. I am fairly new to SQL so any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You just need the current week when it is not present in the data.  That is easily handled using a default value for `lead()`:

```
select the_week, t.customerid, t.score
from (select DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE FROM created_at), WEEK) AS week, 
             customerid, score,
             date_trunc(extract(date from lead(created_at, 1, current_timestamp) over (partition by customerid order by created_at)), WEEK) as next_week
      from t
     ) t cross join
     unnest(generate_date_array(t.week,
                                date_add(t.next_week, interval -1 week),
                                interval 1 week
                               )) the_week;
```

The only change is adding a third argument to `lead()` for the default date when there is none.

Comment: thanks again! I think there is an extra bracket at the end of the date_trunc expression on line 4, but when I remove it I get the following error: No matching signature for analytic function LEAD for argument types: TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP. Supported signature: LEAD(ANY, [INT64], [ANY]) at [7:34]

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error. I've tried changing the datatype of the created_at field so that it is not a timestamp, but it does not seem to be working. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: @Sara . . . The default argument is the third argument, not the second.  I fixed the answer.